# Error when trying to ask for user permission for notification

Tags: swift, notifications

I try to setup the notifications for my app. I do what it says to do in this tutorial: http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/89942124085/notifications-in-ios-8-part-1-using-swift-what

But my app crashes at

```
var notificationSetting: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil)
```

There is nothing in the console except (lldb)

And i've looked at my logs and this is what i get:

```
Dec  6 21:25:14 iPhoneName <Warning>: Could not create service named com.apple.xcode.debug-gauge-data-providers.procinfo
```

I am on IOS 7 i know that i don't need the user permission on IOS 7 but i wan't it to be compatible with IOS 8 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIUserNotificationSettings` is available in iOS 8.0 and later: [UIUserNotificationSettings Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html)

Your code crashes because the API is not available in iOS 7.